# How to get the name of the class name used in a strategie pattern?

Tags: vb.net, class, design-patterns

I have a contextStrategie :

```
Shared Sub New()
    If ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.GetValues("Context").ToString = "Custom" Then
        _context = New CustomHandler
    Else
        _context = New XMLHandler
    End If
End Sub
```

I'm trying (for test purpose) to obtain the name of the class used for my instance :

```
Dim context As ContextStrategie = New ContextStrategie()
'what I tried : 
test.InnerText = context.GetType.Name
```

What I tried return *ContextStrategie*, which is useless to me.

Any way to obtain either *CustomHandler* or *XMLHandler*?

Answer (score 0):

GetType is a function - try context.GetType().Name.

Comment: Still return ContextStrategie.

Comment: In VB parentheses can be omitted for parameterless functions.